# Erro no Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 não pode remover ponto de interrupção

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

No meu projeto eu tenho um sólido ponto de interrupção no Visual Studio que não consigo remover. Posso adicionar outros pontos de interrupção. Alguns removidos, mas alguns não. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia editar sua pergunta com algum screenshot? Isso vai detalhar e facilitar na ajuda.

Comment: Pronto, veja o para bem em cima do set; e bem estrando pois não consigo remover ele

Comment: Tente ir no menu Debug - Delete All Breakpoints

Comment: Deu certo! agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Veja também em Debug - Windows - Breakpoints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode deletar todos os *breakpoints* utilizando o menu **debug | Delete All Breakpoints**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para visualizar todos os *breakpoints* que sua solução tem, você pode ver em **Debug | Windows | Breakpoints**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, eu nunca tinha visto este erro

Comment: Tive algo parecido essa semana no VS 2017.